# Splitting a record into 12 months based on the date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have the data in the below format stored in a pandas dataframe

```
PolicyNumber    InceptionDate
    1         2017-12-28 00:00:00.0
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEfLT.png

I want to split this single record into 12 records based on the inception date. For eg,

```
    1        2017-12-28 00:00:00.0
    1        2018-1-28 00:00:00.0
    1        2018-2-28 00:00:00.0
    1        2018-3-28 00:00:00.0
          .
          .
    1        2018-11-28 00:00:00.0
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I assume you have a larger df with more and different PolicyNumber InceptionDate pairs right?

Comment: @user2246849 Yes, I have a large dataset with different policy numbers and inception date pairs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.date_range` to generate a list of date range then explode the column

```py
df['InceptionDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['InceptionDate'])
df = (df.assign(InceptionDate=df['InceptionDate'].apply(lambda date: pd.date_range(start=date, periods=12, freq='MS')+pd.DateOffset(days=date.day-1)))
      .explode('InceptionDate'))
```

```
print(df)

   PolicyNumber InceptionDate
0             1    2018-01-28
0             1    2018-02-28
0             1    2018-03-28
0             1    2018-04-28
0             1    2018-05-28
0             1    2018-06-28
0             1    2018-07-28
0             1    2018-08-28
0             1    2018-09-28
0             1    2018-10-28
0             1    2018-11-28
0             1    2018-12-28
```

To convert it to your original format from datetime type

```py
df['InceptionDate'] = df['InceptionDate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

```
   PolicyNumber               InceptionDate
0             1  2018-01-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-02-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-03-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-04-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-05-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-06-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-07-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-08-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-09-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-10-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-11-28 00:00:00.000000
0             1  2018-12-28 00:00:00.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it is not working for large datasets

Comment: @Venugopal It will be very slow since usage of `apply` and `explode`

Comment: So have can we solve it? My dataframe size is 654594 rows and 46 columns

Comment: @Venugopal No good idea.